# Django error: Invalid column name 'id'

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models, pyodbc

I'm having difficulty understanding why one of my queries is failing.

I'm using pyodbc to connect to a SQL Server database on a Django application.  All my other queries are working fine, except for one.  Here's the relevant info:

**Model**

```
class ReportTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(db_column='Name', blank=True)
    template = models.TextField(db_column='Template', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ReportTemplateTbl'
```

**Function**

I used 'Abstract' in the example below because it is a known value.

```
get_initial(self):
    my_template = ReportTemplate.objects.get(name='Abstract')
    return {'abstract': my_template.template}
```

**Error**

When the application runs through this function, it returns the following error:

> ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'id'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

The variable info seems to indicate pyodb is attempting to search

> u'SELECT **[ReportTemplateTbl].[id]**, [ReportTemplateTbl].[Name], [ReportTemplateTbl].[Template] FROM [ReportTemplateTbl] WHERE [ReportTemplateTbl].[Name] = ? '

I'd really like to understand what I'm doing wrong here and am trying to avoid making a manual query.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/), the `id` column is created automatically. This behavior can be overridden by [specifying another attribute as the primary key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) in the Model subclass:

```
class ReportTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(db_column='Name', blank=True, primary_key=True)
    template = models.TextField(db_column='Template', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ReportTemplateTbl'
```